# Zorn's lemma relating to a family of sets F

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, order-theory

Let F be a family of sets having properties $(Z_1)-(Z_3)$ for Zorn’s lemma. Assume that F has no maximal element. Then show that for any $A ∈ F$ there is $x \not\in A$ s.t. $A ∪ {x} ∈ F$.

In the textbook it says:
Theorem 3.31 (Zorn’s lemma). Let F be a family of sets with the following properties:

(Z1) ∅∈F;

(Z2) if A∈F and $B\subset A$,then B∈F;

(Z3) if $C \subset F$ is a chain,then $\bigcup$C∈F.

Then F has a maximal element; i.e., there is a set A ∈ F such that there is no B ∈ F with $A \subset B$.

However, it is clearly shown that F has to have a maximal element so isnt the question contradicting itself?

Comment: Zorn's lemma is a theorem of ZFC (Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory with the axiom of choice) but not of ZF (when we don't assume the axiom of choice), so if we assume we're working in ZF, then the conclusion of Zorn's lemma doesn't follow from $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$.  If it helps, however, you may simply assume $F$ only satisfies $Z_2$ rather than all three conditions, as that's all you need.

Comment: Can you give more context for where this problem appears?  For instance, if it is a step in the _proof_ of Zorn's lemma, then you do not yet actually know that $F$ must have a maximal element since you haven't proved Zorn's lemma yet.

Comment: Which one is THE textbook?